# MicroSim PSPICE - Possible for a component to take on the value of another?

Tags: simulation, pspice

In MicroSim PSPICE, is there a way I can assign a value to a component such that it is a multiple of another component?

example:  Resistor A = 10K.  I want resistor B to = 20K, but I want to specify it as B=2*A.  This way, I can change A and B will follow.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `.param` statements to define both `A` and `B`, something like this: `.param A=10k B=2*A`, then assign those values to the resistors (you'll probably have to use curly braces, like this: `{A}` and `{B}`).

Comment: Thanks a concerned citizen - this worked great.